# Magento 2 messages are not displayed on homepage

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, newsletter, cookie, messages

I am working on a Magento 2.1.2 project, theme Porto. I installed the MageMonkey extension for Mailchimp integration.

I strugle with displaying the messages of successful / unsuccessful subscription to newsletter on the homepage. On local, everything works as intended but on preprod server the `afterRenderResult()` method of `Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin` is not called, so no `mage-messages` cookie is set.

On preprod if I visit another page, the messages are displayed.

Has anyone had this problem ?

I even have deployed a preprod database on local thinking that the problem  is in the database.

Maybe it is a caching problem ?

Comment: After you created the plugin, have you deleted your `var/di` and `var/generation` directories?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson of course. Everything in var/ and pub/static/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you return json response.

I also have problem with it.

I find initial commit when add MessagePlugin 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/541ec806cae729df118b7844f5d105cbf1a6cec6

This code check is your response is not json

```
if (!($subject instanceof Json)) {
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php#L83